# Regular Expression for Jmeter for http-response header

Tags: jmeter

How to use regular expression extractor to extract Etag from http-header response?

I've the following output from my get and I want to extract `Etag` and use it in my next case where i've to pass it in my `http-header` to do `If-None-Match`. I've tried the following: `\Etag:\s?` and have chosen "Headers" in "Response Field to Check". But I don't see this value being sent to my header.

```
Thread Name: Fetch_Links 1-1
Sample Start: 2012-05-24 10:15:10 PDT
Load time: 135
Latency: 131
Size in bytes: 4950
Headers size in bytes: 641
Body size in bytes: 4309
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Response code: 200
Response message: OK
```

I'm using 2.6 version of jmeter. Thank you in advance.

Comment: See also [Phrases to avoid](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help4). -- And the ETag is typically absent for generated content. So you might not be able to find it, no matter the regex.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to extract the ETag in JMeter (Regular Expression Extractor - Headers) with the following parameters:

Regular Expression: ETag: "(.*?)"

Template: $1$

Then add a HTTP Header Manager to pass the value of the Etag with 'If-None-Match'.

Comment: oh!!! not sure why mine doesn't work.. can you please tell me if it you are using 2.6 version of jmeter?

Comment: I'm using JMeter 2.3.4 (which comes by default in ubuntu).

Side note: Just make sure the Header 'ETag' is being sent by the server (if apache this may help [Apache FileETag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#fileetag) )